# Loading table rows to array of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this demo. How can I export each row of the table in an array inside of an array?

I need the output like like

```
arrayofArray = [
                 [49, 16, 135,  32, 53],
                 [51, 16, 140,  34, 55],
                 [66, 12' 140,  36, 50]
]
```

```js
var length =  $('table tbody tr').length;   
var arrayofArrays =[];
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
   arrayofArrays.push(parseInt($('table tbody tr:eq('+i+') td').text().trim()))
} 

console.log(arrayofArrays);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td align="center"> 49 </td>
    <td align="center"> 16 </td>
    <td align="center"> 135 </td>
    <td align="center"> 32 </td>
    <td align="center"> 53 </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center"> 51 </td>
    <td align="center"> 16 </td>
    <td align="center"> 140 </td>
    <td align="center"> 34 </td>
    <td align="center"> 55 </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center"> 66 </td>
    <td align="center"> 12 </td>
    <td align="center"> 140 </td>
    <td align="center"> 36 </td>
    <td align="center"> 50 </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like you are just missing the loop over all the TD's in the row. You are just grabbing the first TD

Comment: @MonaCoder As Adam said, you need a an inner for loop to iterate the elements of the array contained in the array of arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let arrayOfArrays = [];

//You can iterate each table row of the table body like so
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
    //Declare a new array object to hold all cell values for this row
    let newArray = [];
    //Iterate each table cell of the row, currently this refers to the table row
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
         newArray.push(parseInt($(this).text()));
    });
    //Push row array into main array
    arrayOfArrays.push(newArray);
});
```

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks for reply but my question is loading array from a table not table to array :-)

Comment: @MonaCoder I'll change my answer, one minute.

Comment: @MonaCoder Updated the answer for you, sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to do originally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VanillaJs version.

```js
let table = document.querySelector("table"),
    tBody = table.tBodies[0];

console.log(
  Array.from(tBody.rows)
    .map(row => Array.from(row.cells)
      .map(cell => cell.innerText * 1))
);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"> 49 </td>
      <td align="center"> 16 </td>
      <td align="center"> 135 </td>
      <td align="center"> 32 </td>
      <td align="center"> 53 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"> 51 </td>
      <td align="center"> 16 </td>
      <td align="center"> 140 </td>
      <td align="center"> 34 </td>
      <td align="center"> 55 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"> 66 </td>
      <td align="center"> 12 </td>
      <td align="center"> 140 </td>
      <td align="center"> 36 </td>
      <td align="center"> 50 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```